# .to_time different movement from documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I use rails4.2.4

My `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
```

### Doc

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-to_time

say

> "2012-12-13T06:12".to_time         # => 2012-12-13 06:12:00 +0100
>
> "2012-12-13T06:12".to_time(:utc)   # => 2012-12-13 05:12:00 UTC

### My code

I try this

```
p "2012-12-13T06:12".to_time
p "2012-12-13T06:12".to_time(:utc)
```

result

```
2012-12-13 06:12:00 +0900
2012-12-13 06:12:00 UTC
```

### Summary

document say `2012-12-13 05:12:00 UTC` 
my code say `2012-12-13 06:12:00 UTC`

doc 1 hour diffrence.
but my code same( I think occur 9 hours difference ).

Comment: Probably [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's just a typo in documentation. Because date/time in a string doesn't tell anything about time zone. So you can either assume it's a local time with `.to_time`(which is `.to_time(:local)`) or that this time is in UTC with `.to_time(:utc)` depending on application needs.